# Count of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

I am having trouble writing a query that sums the occurrence of all values in 2 columns. I have a table with the following structure:

```
+-----------+------------+
| player1ID | player2ID  |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | 2          |
| 1         | 3          |
| 2         | 3          |
| 1         | 4          |
+-----------+------------+
```

After running the query I want a result table like this:

```
+-----------+------------+
| playerID  | count      |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | 3          |
| 2         | 2          |
| 3         | 2          |
| 4         | 1          |
+-----------+------------+
```

I have tried the following query

```
select g1.player1ID, g1.count1 + g2.count2 
from 
    (select player1ID, count(*) from table group by player1ID) as g1, 
    (select player2ID, count(*) from table group by player2ID) as g2 
where player1ID = player2ID
```

but that only gives the count if the player occurs in both columns (player1ID & player2ID) but won't come up if it only occurs in one or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) in a derived table like this:

```
select player, count(*) as count
from (
  select player1id player from table1
  union all
  select player2id player from table1
) sub
group by player;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31d23/1)

Comment: that works perfectly! thank you, seems so simple now, will mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` to combine the two columns.  Then do the aggregation:

```
select playerID, count(*)
from ((select player1ID as playerID from table) union all
      (select player2ID as playerID from table)
     ) t
group by playerID;
```